# Decomposition by eigenspaces exists simultaneously between two matrices

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjacency-matrix

I am studying the relation of the symmetric matrix and its eigenvalues and eigenvectors to understand the graph features from its adjacency matrix.

Suppose that matrix B with size n whose elements are all one, and A is a symmetric matrix with size n. It consists of zero and one, and its diagonal components are all zero. If A is completely divided by eigenspace with a dimension greater than one, B - A has at least one eigenvector with one dimension.

It seems correct, but I cannot construct the proof.

Comment: What do you mean by "A is completely divided by eigenspace with a dimension greater than one"?

Comment: Did you prove the claim for $n=2$ and $n=3$? Is there a pattern that suggests a proof by induction?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I will test for some sample and refine the situation later.